# How to remove row if outlier value in one column for multiple data frames in a list

Tags: r

```
age <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)
freq <- runif(100)
age1 <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)
freq1 <- runif(100)
df1 <- data.frame(age, freq)
df2 <- data.frame(age1, freq1)
list <- list(df1, df2)
```

How can I remove the rows in which age is an outlier and repeat this for all data frames in the list? Also, how do I remove the rows in which frequency is an outlier? If either one is an outlier (relative to other values of the same type), I want to remove the row.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining an outlier for these problems? Since you are generating according to a uniform distribution,  nothing should be considered an outlier.

Comment: @G5W To be honest, I didn't know how to simulate random data which has outliers in it and I cannot share the actual data set I am working with. How would it be done if there were outliers present in the data?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, what matters is *do you need help detecting outliers, or just removing the rows indicated by your outlier detecting function?* If you already have a function that does outlier detection how you want, then that's fine and we can move on - we can help you remove all rows indicated by some function, it doesn't matter whether they're outliers or whatever.

Comment: If you do need help with the outlier detection, you can easily put in an outlier or two in your sample data, e.g., `age[17] = 200; freq1[47] = 1.1`. But since "outlier" doesn't have a strict definition you also need to describe the method you'd like to use for outlier detection.